# NoSQL schema for weather data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using NodeJS and MongoDB for a weather app that takes the weather info from a logger, saves it to a database, and relays the data to the browser in real-time.  It is hosted [here](http://www.ipsacademy.org/weather) with code [here](https://github.com/chintanp/weather_station) which has project details and explanation.

I am saving the weather data to the mongolab cloud-db like so:

```
// Save to cloud db on MongoLab
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, cloud_db) {
  cloud_db.collection('raw_data', function(err, collection) {
    if(!err) {
        collection.insert(dbString, function(docs) {
            collection.count(function(err, count) {
                if(!err) {
                    console.log("Saved to mongolab");
                }
            });
        });
     }
  });
});
```

and the document in db looks like:

```
{
  "lat": "22.65587",
  "long": "75.82626",
  "date": "2014/08/23",
  "time": "20:10:00.000",
  "temp_c": "25.2",
  "humidity": "86.5",
  "pressure_mbar": "939.0",
  "wind_dir": "85.9",
  "wind_speed_mps": "0.8",
  "rain_mm": "0.0",
  "solar_rad_wpsqm": "-3.8",
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "53f8a7d840ecdfe006b0e3be"
  }
}
```

I was wondering if this was the best possible schema for storing the data in terms of speed of data retrieval and ease of use.

Another concern is handling the units. I have named the quantities with units in them. Is there any other way this can be handled better ?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably store the numeric values also as numbers and not as strings. This makes data retrieval and manipulation easier. Also have a look [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) for the coordinates. Date and time should be one field and conform to the ISO date format so you can easily parse it with JS and all other programming languages.